# Iterate a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Let's say we have

```
typedef struct Node{
int num;
struct Node *next;
} node;

node *next1 = NULL;
node node1 = {1, &next1};
node *next0 = &node1;
node node0 = {0, &next0};
node *start = &node0;
```

Why does the following not work to iterate over it (we get into an infinite loop)?

```
node *p = start;
while (p != NULL){p = p->next; }
```

Comment: This code is way too far from being a [mcve].

Comment: What is `end`? [mcve] Please.

Comment: I've corrected. I'm just trying to iterate until the next pointer is NULL.

Comment: One problem is that `&next1` is not null — variables never have NULL as the address.  You need `node node1 = {1, NULL};` or thereabouts as the end of the list.  You have too many nodes and node pointers for a 2-item list.

Comment: Take a look at your code again... What is the `next` member supposed to be? What is its type? Then what is `next1`? What is its type? And more importantly what is `&next1` and what is its type?

Comment: Looks like you didn't set the `next` element properly in your list nodes. The reason: `node *next1 = NULL` but `node1 = { 1, &next1 }` sets the `next` element of `node` to the *address* of `next1` which is not NULL. `next` is already a pointer to `struct Node`, so you want `node1 = { 1, next1 }` etc.

Comment: best way to avoid headaches like you've caused yourself is to write a function that creates and appends a new node to the "list"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `next`'s type is supposed to be a `struct Node` I believe? `next1`'s type is NULL above I believe. `&next1`'s type is an address I believe, I'm not sure of it's type!

@lurker I've tried your suggestion but get into "expression must have a constant value" situation. (This is in global space, if it matters).

@ChrisTurner Yes I may optionally do the in the future, I'm just trying to grasp the fundamentals.

Comment: Not the values, the *types*. The `next` member is of type `struct Node *`, the type of `&next1` is `struct Node **`. Don't you see a difference there? With `&next1` you get a pointer to the variable `next1`, not where it points.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, I think I get it... the variable `next1` is of type  `node *` while the `next` member is of type `struct Node*` which is equivalent to `node *`. So in order to assign the member `next` to the correct type we need to assign it to a variable of type `node *` which is equivalent to type `struct Node*` which is represented by the variable `next1`. Was that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is in the below statement

```
node node1 = {1, &next1}; /* node1 next field should be next1 not &next1 */
```

It should be

```
node node1 = {1, (struct Node*)next1}; /* similarly for node0 */
```

Here is the working code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
        typedef struct Node{
                int num;
                struct Node *next;
        } node;

        node *next1 = NULL;
        node node1 = {1, (struct Node*)next1};
        node *next0 = &node1;
        node node0 = {0, (struct Node*)next0};
        node *start = &node0;

        node *p = start;
        while (p != NULL){
                printf("%d \n",p->num);
                p = p->next;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this instead of your confusing declarations.

```
node node1 = {1, NULL};
node node0 = {0, &node1};
node *start = &node0;
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all learn bit more about link list. Your list creation codes are totally wrong. Read my comment in below code to understand your mistakes:-

```
node *node1 = {1, NULL};//or {1,NULL} not the address of pointer, next1 is pointing to NULL, here you have created the first node
//node *next0 = &node1;// what are you doing here and what are you doing below
//node node0 = {0, &next0};//wrong
node node0 = {0, NULL};// here you have created the second node
node *start = &node0;// you have assign the address of second node to start

//you need to join both the nodes to make it a list
start->next = node1;
```

Also you can implement like below:-

```
node *node1 = {1, NULL};//create first node here
node *next0 = {0, node1};//create second node and link to first node already created in above code
node *start = node0;// now start is pointing to the first node of the list
```

Now below code will work.

```
  node *p = start;
  while (p != NULL){p = p->next; }
```

Comment: I've tried this but get a "expression must have a constant value" error on the line `node node1 = {1, next1};` and "expected a ;" on the line `start->next = node1;`. This is in global space if it matters.

Comment: Try with the second option. Also `node *node1` did you forget to add *?

Comment: I did forget the * in `node node1 = {1, next1};`. Your second option works, thanks!